# How to reproduce javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException using camel and http-client 3 and fix it

Tags: java, ssl, https, jetty, apache-camel

I have issue. We have security connection with a client. Locally all requests passed fine to remote server. But on demo we have the same url but admin configured certificate and looks like certificate is self-signed certificate that throws the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
```

we use camel 2.10.1, http-client (3) and jetty as simulator. If we change just 1 row we can send to real test server or to simulator

```
 <camelContext id="myCamelContext" trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <endpoint id="myServiceUrl" uri="${my.proxy.service.uri}"/>
    </camelContext>
 <from uri="direct:my.service"/>
<to ref="myServiceUrl"/>


my.proxy.service.uri=jetty:http://simulator:18884/Transaction/
```

I found out the following record in log:

```
INFO (main) [SslContextFactory] No keystore or trust store configured.  ACCEPTING UNTRUSTED CERTIFICATES!!!!!
```

Request are fine for simulator but I tried to fix demo issue blindly and I found out solution to accept all certificates but it didn't help:

```
import org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpClientConfigurer;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class MyHttpClientConfigurer implements HttpClientConfigurer {
    protected final Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void configureHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient) {
l.debug("*******************");
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

// set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                               String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                               String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
                }
            }}, new SecureRandom());

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
            Scheme httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", 443, sf);
            SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
            schemeRegistry.register(httpsScheme);

// apache HttpClient version >4.2 should use BasicClientConnectionManager
//            ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
////            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
//            httpClient = new HttpClient();
//httpClient.setHttpConnectionManager(cm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
}
```

and added it into route

```
 my.proxy.service.uri=jetty:http://simulator:18884/Transaction?httpClientConfigurerRef=myHttpClientConfigurer
```

when I fired to real test server

```
https://testserver.***.com/Transaction
```

from my local machine everything is ok, but on demo we've got SSLHandshakeException

so the questions are:

1. How to reproduce exception javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException locally
2. How to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think when you try to access the real test server , you still need to add the option of "httpClientConfigurerRef=myHttpClientConfigurer" into the uri.

Comment: I did it and I saw that option was included into url in log. Perhaps my workaround was not pretty clean. I found out another one. If it will help i'll post it